# Get a part of content from a url

Tags: php

I don't know if you are able to do this, but...

Is there anyway to get a part of the content from a URL ?

Like if I have this:

```
<protected>false</protected>
<followers_count>6</followers_count>
<profile_background_color>00afe0</profile_background_color>
```

(The whole content is from [Twitter](http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=SlogaNator))

But only want the `<followers_count>6</followers_count>` part?

Somebody who know how to do this?
(I hope you guys know what I mean by this)

PS. Anything above is JUST an example

PSS. Not just gona use this for xml, etc [this](https://graph.facebook.com/sloganator) format too (Which I don't know the name of)

Yes, I know that I could just use the `file_get_contents`-offset and maxlen thing, but the problem is, that I don't always know, where the part I'm looking for is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a native XML parser such as [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to find the value of a specific piece of content.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is called XML. PHP has a [built-in XML parser](http://php.net/SimpleXML) which will allow you to extract the data you need.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(
          'http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=SlogaNator'
       );

$follower_count = (int) $xml->followers_count; // int(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=SlogaNator');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

echo $xml->followers_count; # 6
```

"Let's give this guy minuses because he doesn't know you shouldn't parse XML with RegExp" version...

```
preg_match('#<followers_count>([0-9]+)</followers_count>#is', $xml, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; # 6
```

Comment: Which is why he came on SO to ask how it was correctly done.  At some point in time you didn't know either.

Comment: @Justin Lucas, yes, but I have a feeling he will ignore it and go with "easiest" solution... if he knows what is XML, he should know that there is a parser for it, and not using `offset and maxlen` thing... I showed how it can be done.

Comment: @webarto Sorry that I don't know everything about PHP yet D:

Comment: @Moiblpadde, I have nothing against you but, simple Google search, "how to xml with php" would lead you to Justins answer...

Comment: @webarto Just that It's not only xml, but everything, depends on which website, that I'm gonna get the stats from... (Twitter was just an example)... And believe me, I always do some google searches, before asking...